# Assembling Software RAID in Live CD for data recovery

Tags: raid, software-raid, live-cd, lvm

I need help recovering some data that's on my RAID which is on a LVM on my server running Ubuntu.

What happened was I deleted the logical volume that controlled my swap space which was on a partition on drives sda2, sdb2, sdc2, and sdd2 in RAID1.

This foobared my whole system for one reason or another. Booting leave me with grub rescue and an error saying that it is an unknown filesystem.

When I boot to a live cd I can see my RAID arrays and I can even start them up. However, it doesn't appear to mount them anywhere so I can't see the data.

I am in the live cd now and I have done sudo apt-get install mdadm lvm2 so it should be mounting them correctly. I just can't see why it wouldn't.

Please any help is appreciated here.

Here is some output.

By the way, there are 3 RAIDs, 1) /boot 100mb RAID1, 2) swap 10gb RAID1, 3) root 990GB RAID5

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
aufs                  124M  101M   18M  86% /
none                  2.0G  324K  2.0G   1% /dev
/dev/sde1             2.0G  826M  1.2G  42% /cdrom
/dev/loop0            667M  667M     0 100% /rofs
none                  2.0G  164K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 2.0G   28K  2.0G   1% /tmp
none                  2.0G   92K  2.0G   1% /var/run
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /var/lock
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/md1               91M   73M   15M  84% /media/5ac3dbf1-a6c5-409c-96ae-edc6e27992c7

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/fstab 
aufs / aufs rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/sda2 swap swap defaults 0 0
/dev/sdb2 swap swap defaults 0 0
/dev/sdc2 swap swap defaults 0 0
/dev/sdd2 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to try and do something very similar.  The issue if I remember correctly is that there are a series of configuration files which mdadm and lvm use to assemble the partitions and volumes.  Of course these don't exist on the live cd, and so you either have to hand assemble them.... or or or or.  One of the files off the old system is lvm.conf.  This if I remember correctly contains the divisions of your lvm partitions including cylinder numbers, etc..  As for mdadm....  I can't remember the configuration file off the top of my head.  Try mdadm.conf maybe...  Can't remember.  Anyhow, I am going to bounce and see what else I can find.  Good luck.

Comment: check this out for LVM ..http://linuxwave.blogspot.com/2007/11/mounting-lvm-disk-using-ubuntu-livecd.html